# How to set rowspan using PHPExcel library for pdf with table?

Tags: pdf, phpexcel, html-table

I want to generate a PDF file with a report as a table. I need to set rowspan. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do here. What exactly do you mean by rowspan?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that you need to merge cells in PHPExcel, then

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A3');
```